# Unable to update a Pull Request on Github if the main branch has new commits

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-push

My team is running into an issue with a workflow that used to work fine for me. Or at least I remember it working fine.

// TL;DR

After rebasing the local version of `feature-branch` with the local `main` branch, I'm unable to push the local `feature-branch` to the existing *remote* `feature-branch`. ***How does one deal with this? Or is there a better workflow when creating pull requests?***

// Here's the full scenario:

1. To start building my feature I run `git checkout -b feature-branch` while on the `main` branch.
2. The above puts me in the `feature-branch`. I build my feature and then run `git push -u origin feature-branch` to push the branch to github.
3. I create a *pull request* on github and have others make comments. I make some changes to local `feature-branch` and run `git push` to update the remote branch.
4. My *pull request* is approved and I'm ready to rebase and merge w/ `main` branch, BUT there have been other commits to the `main` branch since my pull request went live. *Github is unable to do the rebase and merge as there are conflicts.* Hence I need to rebase my changes on top of the `main` branch locally, fix and then push. The way I do this is:

   1. Locally, I switch to `main` branch and run `git pull`. This pulls in all the latest changes from `main`.
   2. Locally I switch to my `feature-branch` and then run `git rebase main`. This rebases my changes on top of the new changes in the `main` branch. I fix conflicts during the rebase.
   3. I try to run `git push` to update the remote `feature-branch` but this errors saying the remote and local branch have diverged. I thought I used to do this all the time but maybe I'm mistaken. ***What is the typical/good/correct workflow for this?***

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: "Typical" probably has an answer but only GitHub (which would be able to see all PRs) would be able to provide accurate statistics. "Good" is a matter of opinion. Some hate the local-rebase-and-forced-push, some love it. My sympathies are more towards the "love it" side but not fully over that way; this requires a team that understands Git pretty well. "Correct" has multiple (non-opinion) answers but they're not very helpful as you have already summarized things, between this and matt's answer and comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the rebase is supposed to be for. Either the pull request can merge to main or it can't. If it can, merge it. Done! If it can't because there are merge conflicts, then  reverse merge:

- fetch
- merge main into feature branch
- resolve any conflicts
- push

Now the pull request will merge cleanly into main.

If your feature branch is long lived (it takes you days to finish) you should be reverse merging every day to reduce the pain.

Comment: Thanks for the response @matt! So this makes sense, however by merging main onto feature branch it will create a messy git history no? The reason for the rebase is so that our git history remains clean with no merge commits. Am I mistaken here?

Comment: You're not mistaken, though I happen to disagree about what's clean. Ok: If you don't want merge commits, ask GitHub to do a squash-and-merge. Or ask GitHub to do a rebase-and-merge. But don't _you_ do the rebase, not after you've started the pull request.

Comment: I see. Yeah so typically we as Github to do the rebase-and-merge, but when there is a conflict we can't. At that point we may have no choice but to reverse merge as you stated. The only other option is to rebase locally and push up to a new remote branch (essentially scrapping the first PR). This seems like a worse option, so I think reverse merging will be our best bet. Appreciate your thoughts matt!

Comment: Your summary is spot on. I do not know how GitHub would respond to being asked to rebase something that contains a merge; I've never done it.

Comment: matt I just came across `git push --force` to update the remote branch after a rebase. This would overwrite the history on the remote branch. I don't like this option as it would confuse/destroy any comments on the pull request. Just adding this point here for discussion sake.